# How to access mac files(images) in iPad application running on iPad

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, xcode4, uiimageview

Im pretty new to Xcode.
I made a simple app which shows an image in UIImageView.
I used following code:

```
- (IBAction)btnClicked:(id)sender {
[imgBox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DSC01522.jpg"]];
}
```

The images were copied in project by creating a new group "trial images" and adding images to it by right clicking on project navigator.

I am facing the following issue: When I run the app on simulator, I can see the Images. But I can't see them in iPad.
Why is it so? And can anyone please explain me or provide a link where these concepts of file access are explained.
Finally, I need to access iPad images through my app. How I manage that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure your image name is exact "DSC01522.jpg". Device is case sensitive.
2. Try [UIImagePickerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) to get access to iPad's image.

Comment: no issue there. The same app is running on simulator without any code change.

Comment: yes. It seems it was a silly mistake on my part. wrote ".jpg" instead of ".JPG". Thanks anyway.

Comment: @nitz19arg You are welcome. Many other guys also encounter this problem.